# IONIC v2, iOS PUSH, How to catch errors on register

Tags: ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications

I am doing an IONINC v2 project.  iOS PUSH notification.  I have this working on ANDROID....   but not iOS. App works.. but...this.push.register() never happens.  I am looking for a way to return an error or some response code below, to figure out why this is not responding with a TOKEN.
thanks

```
    alert('---  ABOUT TO DO PUSH TOKEN CODE  -----');
console.log('=== About to look for TOKEN');
this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
  //  This never happens... never gets to this point in the code.
  console.log('=== About to return TOKEN');
  return this.push.saveToken(t);
}).then((t: PushToken) => {
  console.log('VY***********************************************'); 
  console.log('=== About to SAVE TOKEN');
  console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
  window.localStorage.setItem("deviceToken", t.token);          
  console.log('VY***********************************************'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just incase anyone is interested where this code is being used.
It is a modified version of the IONIC v2 code for app.components.ts
This code is used to register and handle PUSH notifications.
The issue I was having was that the code would compile, and launch on a physical iOS device.  But No TOKEN would be returned.  So the .Catch would return an error.  In my case it was returning that phone gap plug in was not found.  Still checking into this, but I think the real answer is that I do not have IONIC tokens set up properly...

```
   alert('---  ABOUT TO DO PUSH TOKEN CODE  -----');
    console.log('=== About to look for TOKEN');
    this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
      //  This never happens... never gets to this point in the code.
      console.log('=== About to return TOKEN');
      return this.push.saveToken(t);
    }).then((t: PushToken) => {
      console.log('VY***********************************************'); 
      console.log('=== About to SAVE TOKEN');
      console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
      window.localStorage.setItem("deviceToken", t.token);          
      console.log('VY***********************************************'); 
    }).catch(function(error){  
      alert('----error----' + error  );
      console.log('error-----', error);
      console.error(error);});
```

Normally I don't do IONIC...  mostly native.  Please comment...